# Ctrl+Shift+E misconduct in Google SpreadSheet: "Center Align" instead of show results

Tags: google-sheets

When an array formula in Google Spreadsheet overwrites content it shows a warning:

> "warning: one or more of these results' entries may not be displayed.
>   Select ctrl+Shift+E to show them.

This instruction wroked allright until today when the keyboard shortcut "Ctrl+Shift+E" Center Align the text instead of showing results.

Does someone knows whats wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And I just found a workaround.  Instead of ctrl-shift-E, I tried ctrl-E, which is often a keyboard shortcut for center alignment.  Instead of centering, it extends the array formula the way ctrl-shift-E used to.

Comment: Unfortunately there are still problems with ctrl-E